# Python: How to display data depending on the month using Wikimedia API

Tags: python, json, api, url

I'm having trouble displaying the data by month from the Wikimedia API link below. I'm having the users see the contents inside this link when they choose a specific month.

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikipedia/all-access/2018/11/10

When you open the link you can tell on the file that 11 is the month for that link.

So far I have used import JSON and import requests to read the link:

```
url = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikipedia/all-access/2018/11/10"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Now I want able to have users choose a month and it will display the contents for that month like a list of article names, views, and rank? So if a person were to choose January, it will display the data for the month of 01(January) instead of 11.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the month into a variable and inject it into the string with string formatting:

```py
month = 11
url = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikipedia/all-access/2018/{month}/10"

print(url.format(month=month))
```